# JQuery click function and the <a>-Tag horror

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, html-table

i have the following table:

```
<table id="list_table" class="global" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Grund</th><th>Von</th><th>Bis</th><th>Beschreibung</th><th></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><select name="grund[1][1]">
<option value="krank">Krankheit</option>
<option value="urlaub" selected="selected">Urlaub</option>
<option value="sonstiges">Sonstiges</option>
</select></td><td><input name="von[1][1]" value="11.08.2011" onclick="displayDatePicker('von[1][1]')" type="text"></td><td><input name="bis[1][1]" value="16.09.2011" onclick="displayDatePicker('bis[1][1]')" type="text"></td><td><input name="beschreibung[1][1]" value="Blau machen" type="text"></td><td><a href="#" class="saveChangedEntry" uid="1" sid="1"><img src="images/save.png"></a> <a href="#" class="deleteEntry" uid="1" sid="1"><img src="images/delete.png"></a></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And my JQuery is:

```
$('a[class*=saveChangedEntry]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    alert('That's it!');
});
```

So if I click on the link nothing happens ;(
And if i call the class in the more direct way ... even this does not work.

Any hints?

UPDATE:
Ok, something I didn't think about it and you could not know. The table is generated as a result of a couple of events, so I think I need to add the `live()` function to these links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
alert('That's it!');
```

is not properly escaped:

```
alert('That\'s it!');
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yUXpM/)

Comment: It must be something else, because I copied and pasted your code into that example link. Is there more code?

Comment: yes, a lot of additional code. i checked this point and it's the first time in this code-section that i work with <a> and this class

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you wrap your code in a `document.ready`. Also the text you've placed inside the alert contains an unescaped quote:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[class*="saveChangedEntry"]').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        alert('That\'s it!');
    });
});
```

Comment: @Jens, you have to admit it that this was not obvious from your question. What about the second point with the quote? Also try putting in double quotes the `saveChangedEntry` class in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, perhaps I'm not getting the problem here too well, but I think that the issue is with the selector...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.saveChangedEntry").click(function(evt){
       evt.preventDefault();
       alert("foo!");
   });
});
```

Hope I can help

Comment: doesn't work. i will add a fiddle in some minutes... maybe this could help

Comment: shoot, and here me thinking in a lot of upvotess and cheers :), will wait for the fiddle...